# css file inside content-scripts is not working in chrome-extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to inject a css file in a website.

[Here's](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#static-declarative) the method I am using

```
{
//manifest.json

  "name": "newtset",

  "description": "testing",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "/icons/16.png",
    "48": "/icons/48.png",
    "128": "/icons/128.png"
  },

   "content_scripts": [{
     "matches": ["https://github.com/*"],
     "css": ["bg.css"],
     "js": ["script.js"]
    }]
}
```

```
// bg.css

body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```
//script.js

alert("hello")
console.log("script loaded")
```

My java script is running just fine but the css file is not working,

I know that there's [another method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#programmatic) to do this, but It should work with just declaration as mentioned in docs.
It;s not showing any errors in the console.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think the css is working because when I change the body to * it's all black.

Comment: Add `!important` to your declarations. See "CSS specificity overriding" for more info.

Comment: @wOxxOm, That way github.com didn't have a black background. Well, I think it all depends on the original design.

Comment: thanks for your comments, using `!important` its working